# What is the proper way to design a REST API that takes a boolean argument?

Tags: java, rest

Basically I have a rest API like this:

```
/api/drive
```

And it takes a body for `PUT` which is either "true" or "false".

I'm using dropwizard framework with Java, and `boolean drive` is one of my parameters in the `PUT` method of my resource class.

Everything works as expected, but I was testing on Postman and see even if I put another value like "notABoolean" in the request body, the request itself is still successful. It just treats it as "false". Does this align with REST principles, or does it make more sense to throw a `400 BAD REQUEST` error if the body isn't true/false?

Comment: If you treat non boolean as `false` values it's ok. It's not nice to make the API super strict because it would make it difficult to whoever is using it. only throw `400 BAD REQUEST` if the type really shouldn't be allowed somehow.

Comment: Most framework that i know treat non boolean as false. `"True"`, `1`, `true` are converted to `boolean true`

Comment: Seems reasonable to follow the underlying semantics of what the REST library is doing (i.e. `Boolean.valueOf()`) as long as your API contract specifies that behavior. A 400 seems overkill since you can clearly handle a value outside of simple true and false; it would make more sense to return a 400 only if the value was missing entirely.

Answer (score 0):

> Does this align with REST principles, or does it make more sense to throw a 400 BAD REQUEST error if the body isn't true/false?

"It depends".

```
notABoolean
```

That's a perfectly reasonable `text/plain` document, but it isn't a valid [application/json](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8259#section-3) document.

As noted by Mike, `Boolean.valueOf("notABoolean")` has a well defined value; if you have described your API in a way that explicitly restricts this case, then you get what you get.

There are at least three possible status codes that might handle this case.

[422 Unprocessable Entity](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4918#section-11.2) is what you seem to have been expecting - it roughly translates to "yeah, the data is what you said it was, but that really doesn't make any sense here".

If you were to describe your API such that only `application/json` was reasonable, then this test would probably have produced either [415 Unsupported Media Type](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.5.13) (because the client sent `text/plain`) or [400 Bad Request](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.5.1) (because `notABoolean` is not a valid JSON value).

Of course, Strings are valid json values, so the payload below might land you in the same fix

```
"notABoolean"
```

It's an acceptable type, and it is valid, but you are back on the 422 train.

To get DropWizard to return the 422 for you "for free", look into the docs on [validation](https://www.dropwizard.io/1.3.5/docs/manual/validation.html).